# How to avoid the line break between these two forms

Tags: html

I want to avoid line break between the buttons login and Register,So that the two buttons come in the same line

```
    <h1>Are You ready to take the quiz</h1>
      <form action="link1">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
      <form action="link2">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Please just stop editing the question. I've got confused on what to answer ...

Comment: there was some mistakes,very bad mistakes, now finalized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css for that.

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

In order to prevent every `form` element you're using to get inlined, I'd attatch a class to those which you want to inline.

```
<form class="inline" action="link1">
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<form class="inline" action="link2">
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>


form.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxzahzpd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution, I used a container : sameLine so evrithing is in that div will be on the same line

```css
.sameLine{white-space: nowrap;}
.sameLine * {
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Are You ready to take the quiz</h1>
<div class="sameLine">
      <form action="link1">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
      <form action="link2">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
      </form>
 </div>
```